# Error: No suitable driver found for jdbc:omar\mssqlserver01:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=DB1FR;

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to connect java code to SQL server, I am using engine mssqlserver01, database called DB1FR.

I tried opening the server SQL configuration -> TCP/UDP -> IP address and unified al ports to 1433 and dynamic ones to 0. I also tried another engine, restarted the database.

```
public static void addCustomer(int id, String fullName, String email, int creditCardNum, int nationalID) throws SQLException {

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:sqlserver://mssqlserver01:1433;DatabaseName=DB1FR;user=omar;");

    java.sql.Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("INSERT INTO dbo.Customer(CustomerID, full_name, email, creditcardnum, nationalid) VALUES " 
    + id + ", " 
    + fullName + ", " 
    + email + ", " 
    + creditCardNum + ", " 
    + nationalID);

    while (rs.next()) {
        int x = rs.getInt("a");
        String s = rs.getString("b");
        float f = rs.getFloat("c");
    }
}
```

It should insert into the CUSTOMER table those values. But an exception is thrown and the table is not updated.

[image]

Comment: You are using the wrong URL. A JDBC URL for Microsoft SQL Server starts with `jdbc:sqlserver:` not with only `jdbc:`. Please refer to the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver documentation for the correct URL (specifically [Building the Connection URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017)), as the rest of your URL is also wrong.

Comment: And in addition, please learn how to use prepared statements with parameterized statements. Concatenating values into a statement string like you're currently doing makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection and related bugs.

Comment: the current URL is: jdbc:sqlserver://mssqlserver01:1433;DatabaseName=DB1FR;user=omar
I have searched and found that the correct URL should begin with jdbc:sqlserver.

Now the error says The TCP/IP connection to the host mssqlserver01, port 1433 has failed. Do you know where might be the error here?

Comment: @Omar - When you make a significant change to your setup (like changing the connection string) please [edit] your question instead of burying that detail in the comments